# Are all Schedule C deductions available if business income is instead from a K-1?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

If business income is declared on a Schedule K-1 can a individual tax filer effectively claim all of the deductions against that income that are available if the income were instead declared on a Schedule C?

Comment: Schedule C is for sole proprietors and K1 is for partnerships/S-Corps - they're not interchangeable

Comment: @littleadv Yes, but a taxpayer with both entities might elect to structure or collect business income through one instead of the other.

Comment: That makes no sense. If you're a partner in a partnership or an employee of a corporation - how can you collect their income as a sole proprietor? These are separate legal entities.

Comment: @littleadv Hypothetical example: I am one member of a two-member LLC that performs consulting services.  The LLC's OA allows me to consult on an hourly basis independently of the LLC.  Therefore I can choose to bill a consulting hour through the LLC, or through my own sole proprietorship.

Comment: So that allows you to decide whether to split the income with the partnership or not, good for you. What does it have to do with taxes?

Comment: @littleadv: A taxpayer can deduct *a lot* of things on Schedule C as "business expenses."  The question is whether everything that can be deducted on Schedule C can instead be deducted elsewhere if the taxpayer does not file a Schedule C and instead takes the income through the partnership via K-1.

Comment: I think the main confusion you have is that you think that the entity reporting on Schedule C and the entity providing K1 are the same and they just chose which form to use. That's not true. Your "choice of LLC or Schedule C" is nonsense. You're either a sole proprietor, or you're a partner, you can't be both.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're asking - you're asking whether entities that report income on K-1 are allowed to report the expenses as well.

The answer is **yes**, if the entity has incurred expenses they would also be reported to you on the K-1.

In essence - disregarded entities (partnerships or S-Corporations) are, well, disregarded. They don't affect how much taxes you're paying and how these taxes are calculated. I know some people think that by virtue of funneling money through S-Corp instead of Schedule C they can save on taxes, but that's not actually true. S-Corp and Partnerships do however have certain benefits when you have income that is not from your own work (i.e.: if you have profits from the work of other employees).

Comment: I'm asking the opposite question: If the income is "funneled" through the partnership to appear on a K-1 (I assume Box 1) can the individual deduct *all* of the same business expenses he could if he had instead had the income paid directly to him and filed a Schedule C?  (In this scenario the partnership is not reporting or paying any business expenses.  Just imagine the taxpayer can either have the check made out to the LLC, which will pass the amount along to him on a K-1; or the taxpayer can have the check made out to him personally and declared on a 1099-NEC with his tax ID.)

Comment: @feetwet You're conflating unrelated things. If you get income from K-1 - you'll get the related expenses also reported on K-1. You can't deduct random expenses from the K-1 income, only the expenses related to that income reported to you on K-1. What can be reported? The same things that can be reported on Schedule C.

Comment: So you're saying if one wants to deduct a home office and its expenses and supplies, business travel, health insurance, etc. from business income that one reports on a K-1, then all of those deductions have to get onto that same K-1?  (In Box 13?)

Comment: @feetwet  "One" doesn't deduct them. If "one" is a partner in a partnership, "one" has the partnership pay those for them and report as a deductible expense on K-1. Alternatively, "one" can treat them as "unreimbursed partner expense". Here's the IRS instructions for the home office expense as the example: http://irs.gov/publications/p587#en_US_2021_publink1000226431